# ultrapowers of a matrix

Tags: banach-algebras

1)Let A, B, C, D be a Banach algebras, and U be a free ultrafilter. Can we see that ultrapowers of 
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D
\end{pmatrix} equal to \begin{pmatrix}
  (A)_U & (B)_U \\
  (C)_U & (D)_U
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too basic. See Heinrich's paper or Defant-Floret

Comment: Thanks. I saw them, but I didn't see anything about matrices. But they were useful for Hilbert spaces.